# Most probable value given observation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have observed $Z = 3$, where $Z = X + Y$, where $X \sim N(0,9), Y \sim  N(0,4)$. How would I find the most probable value of $X$ that would have given me $Z = 3$?

My attempt at a solution: I was given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so that means $Z \sim N(0+0, 9+4) = N(0,13)$. To find the most probable value of $X$, we would have to find the highest possible probability of $Z$. But $Z$ is not discrete, so every probability at each point is 0, which means the highest probability of $Z$ is 0. Not sure what I would do after this, so I took a different direction.

Now I'm trying to find $E(X|Z=3)$ because I would think the mean is the best measure for the "most probable value of X". We have,

$E(X|Z=3) = E(X|X+Y=3)$. 
At this point, are there properties for conditional expectation involving independent random variables to answer this? I tried to find some but wasn't able to. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd presume the intent is to find the highest *relative* probability (which will be proportional to density), conditional on $Z=3$.

You'll need to know what the conditional distribution of $X|Z=3$ is (e.g. if it wasn't symmetric, knowing the expected value would not be much use).

If you don't know what that particular conditional density is, you might wish to look at the definition of the conditional density.

(Another possibility might be to invoke Bayes theorem.)

Comment: Hello, I found out that the conditional distribution of X|Z = 3 is a normal distribution with mean 0 + 9*(1/13)*(3-0) = 27/13, and the variance 9 - 9*(1/13)*9 = 36/13. Since all normal distributions are symmetric about their mean, I am now free to use expectation, correct?

Comment: Yes, the conditional distribution is indeed normal (I didn't check your mean and variance though), so you can use the conditional expectation as the point with highest relative (conditional) probability.

Comment: Thanks, this means it would simply be the peak of the conditional distribution. As an exercise, I would now like to solve this using your 2nd hint, i.e., by Bayes' Theorem. Would I have to find the distribution of Z=3|X in order to do this?

Comment: Sorry, my brain is foggy at the moment. I think it goes like this: $\hspace{2cm}$ $f_X(x|Z=3) = \frac{f_Z(3|X=x)\cdot f_X(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(3|X=u)\cdot f_X(u)du}$ ... but there are a number of things you can do to simplify that